# Passing Queue Object over IPC in Android

Tags: java, android, ipc, aidl

I have class X that implements Queue.

I want to pass Class X's Object into AIDL interface. When i am importing class X in .aidl  File Eclipse
shows an error and says "could not find import for
class com.test.X." although the class is there.

```
package com.test

public class X implements Queue<byte[]>{


public LinkedList<byte[]> que = new LinkedList<byte[]>();

int push =0, pop = 0;

public Iterator<byte[]> iterate = null;

public X()
{
    iterate = que.iterator();// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
}
```

As searching around on Google i have found that You must create a separate .aidl file for each class you wish to use within your service.So, i have created X.aidl but it didnt work.
can any one suggest something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make your class implementing Parcelable interface. So in your case the declaration will be like:

```
public class X implements Queue<byte[]>, Parcelable {}
```

You can read [here](http://app-solut.com/blog/2011/05/using-self-defined-parcelable-objects-during-an-android-aidl-rpc-ipc-call/) how to implement Parcelable interface.